# If I install ubuntu on my external hard drive, will my data be deleted?

Tags: installation, live-usb, external-hdd

I have an external harddrive that I use to backup my files. But now I want to install ubuntu on it. I was thinking of a LiveUSB instalation, because it would allow me to boot ubuntu from other computers. The problem is, I have alot of data on the hard drive and I want to be able to acces that data from windows (when booted into windows and than connect my HDD to my PC) and from ubuntu.

And is it possible to remove the liveusb instalation without lozing my data? (I have installed ubuntu on my old usb a couple of times and I know I am capable to mes it up without knowing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gparted` to resize the partintion on the USB disk

Install with

> sudo apt-get install gparted

Run it by looking for it on your dash or by typing `sudo gparted` on a terminal.

Re-size it by right clicking on the partition with the right button and choosing 're-size'.

After you resided your partition install Ubuntu side by side inside the USB disk's new unallocated space. If possible do a backup of all the data inside the USB disk before doing any of this, if the files are important you should always take the safe side.

Resizing does not delete the data on the USB disk partition and allows you to free up space for your Ubuntu installation.